# Nuxt.js + Express + Heroku — Axios requests return 404 in production, but not on localhost in dev mode — any solution?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, axios, nuxt.js

I've made a cms for blogging using nuxt.js with express for the server. It uses axios to make asyncData requests to the server before loading each page.

**It works fine when I run it locally**, but when I deploy the site on heroku the axios requests all return 404.

My guess is that the axios requests baseURL is wrong somehow, but when I haven't been able to confirm that. I've confused myself.

I've tried setting the baseURL to the url of the site, I've tried setting it to `http://0.0.0.0:8000`, which is mentioned in the [nuxt.js docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-server/)

I've tried including the modeule `@nuxtjs/dotenv` with `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of my nuxt.config.js file.

My nuxt.config.js file

```
    module.exports = {
      mode: 'universal',

      head: {
        title:'',
        meta: [
          { charset: 'utf-8' },
          { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
          { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content:'' }
        ],
        link: [
          { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png' }
        ]
      },

      loading: { color: '#fff' },

      css: [
        { src: '~assets/stylesheets/global.scss', lang: 'scss' }
      ],

      plugins: [
      ],
      /*
      ** Nuxt.js modules
      */
      modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-module'
      ],

      axios: {

      },

      build: {
        /*
        ** You can extend webpack config here
        */
        extend(config, ctx) {
          // Run ESLint on save
          if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
              enforce: 'pre',
              test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
              loader: 'eslint-loader',
              exclude: /(node_modules)/,

              options : {
                    fix : true,
                    extractCSS : true
                }
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

my server/index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const consola = require('consola')
const passport = require('passport')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')

const app = express()


// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

//Body Parser / Cookie Parser config
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Expresss Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'lkasjdlmsdj18ka124jlsdalkjmlakjc',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

require('./auth_config')(passport)
require('./auth')(app,passport)

//Posts
require('./posts.js')(app, mongoose)


async function start() {

  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server



  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }


  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)
  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

An example of one of the axios routes that queries the database.

```
  app.get("/api/posts/latest-post", async (req, res) => {
    try {
              var result = await PostModel.findOne({published:true}).sort({"date.published.iso": -1}).exec();
              res.send(result);
          } catch (error) {
              res.status(500).send(error);
      }
  });
```

The example here should return the latest post, instead I get an nuxt error message "server error." The same is true for every route that uses axios to request data from the server.

It works exacltly as expected on local host.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: I have very little recollection of this issue. I think it turned out to be something trivial. Since then I have changed over to using Nuxt Generate with Netlify CMS. Which is a much better way of making a blog with Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of axios with a custom config, like this:
axios.create([config]) ->this is the sample
//code starts

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://www.abcdxyz.com/api/',// as you used http://0.0.0.0:8000
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'} // if you like to send details else remove it
});
```

//code ends
You can also use Axios inline but I prefer an extra utils folder and then a new file named 'axiosconfig' and just import it... helps in the MVC

I hope my answer was helpful to you!